# how I can display the names of columns in a JTable with builder editor window eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

How can I display the names of table columns in visual editor eclipse?

I am not able to display the title of the columns.

```
table = new JTable();
table.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED,
    UIManager.getColor("nimbusInfoBlue"),
    UIManager.getColor("nimbusFocus")));
table.setRowHeight(20);
table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
    new Object[][]{
        {null, null, null, null, null, "", null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},},
    //Les titres des colonnes
    new String[]{
        "reference", "CIN/RC", "nom", "prenom",
        "payement", "date payement", "categorie"
    }) {

    boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[]{
        false, false, false, false, false, false, false
    };

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return columnEditables[column];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the JTable in a JScrollPane.

Comment: how to place a table in a JScrollPane ?

Comment: To be complete: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is a link to the Swing tutorial which describes why this approach will work. The section _Adding a Table to a Container_ is the part you are looking for

Comment: how to limit the user to move a column in a JTable component